# Nav Bar Z-index won't work with the Alice Carousel

Tags: reactjs, navigation, tailwind-css, carousel, z-index

I have my tailwind store navigation bar and alice carousel for slide change, but the dropdown nav bar of the desktop view won't appear over the alice carousel, it appear under the alice carousel.

I tried implementing `<div className="bg-white z-10">` to the navigation bar to get it above but it didnt work well

Can you give me correct code to have the navigation bar over the carousel

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by the way, it is i should wrap up the nav bar like like this : `<div className="bg-white sticky top-0 z-50">`

This solves the Z-index not appearing in top question.